# Filtering REST api calls

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm facing  difficulty in finding out REST Api calls being made in browser as there are so many calls being shown in network tab like for image,html etc..How to filter only rest api calls being made using chrome Dev tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a filter option available in Chrome Dev tools
There you can select Ajax which the rest API call you make.